# A better approximation of $H_n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, approximation

I'm convinced that

$$H_n \approx\log(n+\gamma) +\gamma$$ is a better approximation of the $n$-th harmonic number than the classical $$H_n \approx \log(n) +\gamma$$ 
Specially for small values of $n$. I leave some values and the error:

[image: Table of values]
[image: Table 2]

Just to make things clearer, I calculate the value between two numbers as follows.
Say $n$ is the optimal and $a$ is the apporximation, then $E = \frac{n-a}{n}$. $L_1$ stands for my approximation and $L_2$ for the classical one, and the errors $E_2$ and $E_1$ correspond to each of those (I mixed up the numbers).

It is clear that this gives an over estimate but tends to the real value for larger $n$.

So, is there a way to prove that the approximation is better?

---

NOTE: I tried using the \begin{tabular} environment but nothing seemed to work. Any links on table making in this site?

Comment: LaTeX text formatting commands usually don't work, but you could put your numbers in a `\begin{array}` or `\begin{matrix}`. It might be somewhat slow.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but if you're trying to compute "relative error" of the two approximations, shouldn't you be doing $\left|\dfrac{(\text{approximation})-(\text{true value})}{\text{true value}}\right|$? From that, you can try to look at the asymptotic behavior of the two errors as $n\to\infty$...

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I chose the largest first to get a positive number.

Comment: meta: [How do I insert a table when asking a question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question/)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Good to know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, you do better still with $ H_n \approx \gamma + \log \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right),$ with
$$  H_n =  \gamma  + \log \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)   + O \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right). $$
As you can see from the other answers, this minimizes the error among approximations of type $H_n \approx \gamma + \log \left( n + c \right)$ with constant $c,$ by erasing the $\frac{1}{n} $ error term.

A fuller version of the asymptotic above is just

$$  H_n =  \gamma  + \log \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)  + \frac{1}{24 \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2} - \frac{7}{960 \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)^4} + \frac{31}{8064 \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)^6} - \frac{127}{30720 \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)^8} + O \left( \frac{1}{n^{10}} \right). $$

Comment: $n+1/2$ is certainly easier to deal with than $n+\gamma$... :)

Comment: @WillJagy Where do I find theory on such expansion?

Comment: @Peter, the standard asymptotic (in powers of $\frac{1}{n}$) comes from the relationship with the digamma function, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers and  the first formula in the section http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Computation_.26_approximation I did the version with adding $(1/2)$ myself, but it is surely equivalent to the other. There is a good reason that adding $(1/2)$ will erase the first error term in any similar problem, but the explanation is intricate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.

Comment: $H_n\approx log\left(2n+1\right)+\gamma-log(2)$ is better because $log(2)-\gamma < \gamma$.

See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602945/134791 for a series linking $H_n$ and $log\left(2n+1\right)$

Answer (score 10):

The asymptotic expansion of the Harmonic numbers $H_n$ is given by

$$\log n+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

The Maclaurin series expansion of the natural logarithm tells us $\log(1+x)=x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$, and we can use this in your formula by writing $\log(n+\epsilon)=\log n+\log(1+\epsilon/n)$ and expanding:

$$\log(n+\gamma)+\gamma=\log n+\gamma\;\;\;+\frac{\gamma}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

Your approximation is asymptotically better than the generic one because the $\gamma=0.577\dots$ in its expansion is closer to the true coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$ than the illicit coefficient $0$ in the generic formula given by the usual $H_n\sim \log n +\gamma+0/n$. This also explains why it is asymptotically an *over* estimation.

---

As marty said in his answer, the expansion comes from the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula):

$$\sum_{n=a}^b f(n)=\int_a^b f(x)dx+\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(b)-f^{(2k-1)}(a)\right).$$

Here we let $a=1,b=n$ (rewrite the index to a different letter) and $f(x)=1/x$.

Comment: Maybe you can remove al the colours now. Asaf will be thankfull.

Comment: As you wish. ${}$

Answer (score 3):

The true approximation, from the Euler-Maclaurin formula, is
$$H_n = \ln n + \gamma + 1/2n + O(1/n^2).$$

Your expansion is
$\ln (n+\gamma) + \gamma
= \ln \ n + ln(1+\gamma/n)+\gamma
= \ln \ n + \gamma + \gamma/n + O(1/n^2)
$.

Since $\gamma = .577...$, your error is
about $.077/n$,
which is better by .077/.5 ~ .154 ~ 1/6
which explains the table.

I see another answer has just been posted.
If it differs much from mine, I will be surprised.