# Summing Finitely Many Terms of Harmonic Series: $\sum_{k=a}^{b} \frac{1}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

How do I calculate sum of a finite harmonic series of the following form?

$$\sum_{k=a}^{b} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a+1} + \frac{1}{a+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b}$$

Is there a general formula for this? How can we approach this if not?

Comment: You can find good estimates of the $n$-th harmonic number [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

Comment: An approximation is given by $log\left(\frac{2b+1}{2a-1}\right)$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't find a general formula.
All you can do is the use the
standard asymptotic formula
for the harmonic sum

$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k
= \ln n + \gamma 
+\frac1{2n} -\frac1{12n^2} + \frac1{120n^4} + ...
$$

where
$\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$
is the
 Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Your sum would be
$H_b - H_{a-1}$.

Comment: A better asymptotic formula is given by
$$H_n=log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\gamma+\frac{1}{24n^2}-\frac{1}{24n^3}+...$$
$$H_n=log\left(2n+1\right)-log\left(2\right)+\gamma+\frac{1}{24n^2}-\frac{1}{24n^3}+...$$
General closed form formulas can be found here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602945/134791

Comment: Yup. And the $n+1/2$ form works better the Stirling's usual formula for $n!$ also. btw, your two forms are the same, of course.

Comment: I think they deserve being written separately because there are two different comparisons:
$H_n$ approximates better $log(n+\frac{1}{2})$ than $log(n)$ because $$\frac{1}{24n^2}<\frac{1}{2n}$$
$H_n$ approximates better $log\left(2n+1\right)$ than $log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ because $$lim_{n \to \infty}\left(log\left(2n+1\right)-H_n\right)=log(2)-\gamma<\gamma=lim_{n \to \infty}\left(H_n-log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

The first term may be taken out of the generalized Mercator series  for the logarithm of integers https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593145/134791

$$
log\left(n\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=nk+1}^{n(k+1)}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)
$$

to obtain
$$
log\left(n\right)=H_n-1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=nk+1}^{n(k+1)}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)
$$

For odd arguments, partial sums are closer to the limit if the following regrouping is chosen

$$
log(2n+1)=H_n+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=-n}^{n}\frac{1}{(2n+1)k+i}-\frac{1}{k}\right)
$$

This leads to the approximation
$$ log(2n+1)\approx H_n $$

which combined with Fallen's answer finally yields
$$\sum_{k=a}^b\frac{1}{k}\approx log\left(\frac{2b+1}{2a-1}\right)$$

as claimed in my previous comment.

This approximation can also be obtained from a geometrical approximation to the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$. Let each term represent a rectangle with height $\frac{1}{k}$ and unit width centered around $x=k$:

$$\frac{1}{k} \approx \int_{k-\frac{1}{2}}^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dx}{x}$$

Now adding $b-a+1$ of such consecutive approximations the same result is obtained.
$$\sum_{k=a}^b\frac{1}{k}\approx \int_{a-\frac{1}{2}}^{b+\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dx}{x}=log\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)-log\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)=log\left(\frac{b+\frac{1}{2}}{a-\frac{1}{2}}\right)=log\left(\frac{2b+1}{2a-1}\right)$$

Comment: Just noticed this answer. Nice. But, wouldn't the approximation be $log(2n+1)\approx H_n+\log(2)$?

Comment: The expansion for $\log(2n+1)-H_n$ starts $(\log(2) - \gamma ) - \frac{1}{24 n^2} + \frac{1}{24 n^3}$, so we also have $log(2n+1) \approx H_n+\log(2)-\gamma$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H_{x} = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x}$.

So if I'm not wrong, what you are looking for is, $H_{b}−H_{a - 1}$

Answer (score 3):

You can use unsigned Sterling's numbers of the first kind that is A$000254$ in the OEOIS. Just divide the $n^{th}$ term by $n^{th}$ factorial and the answer will be the finite sum. 
  Eg: 
$$1+\frac1{2}+...+\frac1{8} = \frac{109584}{8!}$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: I applaud this insight. +1

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is more for additional information and as an exercise for myself to remember Gosper's algorithm.**

There is no nice closed formula for this. By nice we can take *hypergeometric functions* (functions $f(n)$ such that $f(n+1)/f(n)$ is a rational function) or even finite sums of hypergeometric functions. If there were, in particular you would get a nice closed formula for $H(n):=1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n$.

Assume that $H(n)$ is hypergeometric. Then $1/n=H(n)-H(n-1)$, i.e. $$nH(n)-nH(n-1)=1$$.

Now, since we are assuming $H$ is hypergeometric we get $$nH(n)=\frac{H(n)}{(H(n+1)-H(n))}=\frac{1}{\frac{H(n+1)}{H(n)}-1},$$

which should be rational. So, we are looking for a rational function $K(n):=nH(n)$ such that

$$(n-1)K(n)-nK(n-1)=n-1.$$

Observe that if $a\neq1$ is a pole of $K(n)$ then it would have to be a pole of $K(n-1)$. If $1$ is a pole of $K$ then $-2$ is a pole of $K(n-1)$ and therefore also a pole of $K$. This is impossible because it implies $K$ has infinitely many poles. Therefore $K$ is a polynomial. But there are no polynomials satisfying this equation. In fact, assume $K(n)=an^r+bn^{r-1}+\ldots$. Plug it in the equation and you get that the leading term of the left hand side is $(r-1)an^r$. Therefore we get that $r=1$ and $(r-1)a=1$ from imposing that it should be equal to the right hand side $n-1$. But these equations are impossible.

Thus $H$ is not an hypergeometric function. Further arguments show that it can't be either a finite sum of hypergeometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but too long for a comment:
[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BLimit%5BIntegrate%5B%28%28s%20%2B%201%29%5E%28-n%20-%201%29%20%2B%20s%20-%201%29%2Fs%2C%20s%5D%2C%20s%20-%3E%200%5D%2C%20%7Bn%2C%201%2C%2012%7D%5D)

when entering the Mathematica one liner:

```
Clear[n, s];
Table[Limit[Integrate[((s + 1)^(-n - 1) + s - 1)/s, s], s -> 0], {n, 
  1, 12}]
```

It is not a closed form since I have been told that one cannot have such an indefinite integral in a closed form. But in the Wolfram Alpha answer we have the latexified expression:

$$H(n)=\lim_{s\to 0} \, \int \frac{(s+1)^{-n-1}+s-1}{s} \, ds$$

Answer (score 0):

The formula for sum of H.P. remained unknown for many years, but now I have found the formula as an infinite polynomial.

The formula or the infinite polynomial which is
equal to the sum of th H.P. $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a+d} + \frac{1}{a+2d} + \frac{1}{a+3d} + ........$ is :-

$Sum of H.P. = (1/a)  [1 + \frac{1}{1×(1+b)}(x-1) - \frac{b}{(2×(1+b)(2+b)}(x-1)(x-2) + \frac{b^2}{3×(1+b)(2+b)(3+b)}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) - \frac{b^3}{4×(1+b)(2+b)(3+b)(4+b)}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) + \frac{b^4}{5×(1+b)(2+b)(3+b)(4+b)(5+b)}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5) - .....]$

Here, $b=d/a$ and $x$ is the number of terms upto
which you want to find the sum of the H.P.
Substitute any natural number in place of x and
get the sum of the harmonic series.

For more information, visit https://facebook.com/ElementaryResearchesinMathematics.

I have not provided any proof here since that will be a very difficult task at this platform.