# Finding the nth term of sequence that is neither AP, GP or HP

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $$ \frac{44}{24} , \frac{50}{24}, \frac{54}{24}, \frac{57}{24}, ...$$
Since this is not arithmetic nor geometric series could someone help me find the nth term, please?

---

I know that the difference between the terms is in harmonic progression i.e. $$ \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{8}...$$ But, I don't know how would this help.
Thanks a lot!
By the way, I'm really new here, so I'd really love some suggestions if I did something wrong or anything like that!

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I would call $ \frac{44}{24} , \frac{50}{24}, \frac{54}{24}, \frac{57}{24}, ...$ a sequence rather than a series. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: Oh, yeah sry! Thank you! I hope this would be a nice experience!

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for.  As you are surely aware, there is no simple closed formula for $\sum \frac 1n$.

Comment: @lulu since there is no closed formula for this, I cannot find the nth term for this sequence?

Comment: What does "cannot find" mean?  Of course you can find it, in terms of $\sum \frac 1n$.  My point is just that there isn't some simple closed formula for it, much as one might like one.

Comment: @lulu So by using ∑1/n I can get the nth term, but how?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439177/summing-finitely-many-terms-of-harmonic-series-sum-k-ab-frac1k) and others that come up by searching sum of harmonic series  I would call this a duplicate.

Comment: Well, just copying what you wrote, it is $a_n=\frac {44}{24}+\frac 12\times \sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1k$.

Comment: @lulu and Ross Thank you both of you! I got it!